# creating a function that takes in a string and returns that string with every even letter uppercase

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a function in python that takes in strings and returns every even letter uppercase and odd letter lowercase. 
For instance,

```
def myfunc(my_string):
     #code

myfunc(Python)
```

Returns: pYtHoN

```
(1, p) odd
(2, y) even
(3, t) odd
(4, h) even
(5, o) odd
(6, n) even
```

As you can see all the even indexes are uppercase and odd lowercase.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What is your question?

Comment: We need to see your code to help.

Comment: `"".join(x.lower() if i % 2 == 0 else x.upper() for i, x in enumerate(s))`

Answer (score -2):

```
def alternating_case(s):
    return "".join(
        x.lower() if i % 2 == 0 else x.upper()
        for i, x in enumerate(s)
    )
```